# jwplayer: get video URL onComplete

Tags: jwplayer

I'm trying to get the URL of the video via `jwplayer().getPlaylistItem().file;` onComplete callback, but it's returning nothing.

```
jwplayer().onComplete(function(e) {
    var videoURL = this.getPlaylistItem().file;
    console.log('Completed = ' + videoURL);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be this:

```
var videoURL = jwplayer().getPlaylistItem()['file'];
```

Comment: Regardless of using dot or bracket notation, I'm still not getting the video's URL.

Comment: We use this on - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1436999-example-adding-a-download-button, and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to work.

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
  playlist: "http://content.jwplatform.com/feeds/13ShtP5m.rss",
  displaytitle: false,
  width: 640,
  height: 360
});

jwplayer().onComplete(function(e) {
    var videoURL = this.getPlaylistItem().file;
    console.log('Completed = ' + videoURL);
});
```

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rDs4P/

If it still doesn't work, please provide link where you run the player.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about onComplete but it worth to try:

```
var fileName = jwplayer().config.file
var baseUrl = jwplayer().config.streamer
var videoUrl = baseUrl + "/" + fileName
```